# C#: bytes to UTF-8 string conversion. Why doesn't it work?

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, hex

There is a Chinese character  which is presented in UTF-8 as F0 A4 AD A2. This character is described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

U+24B62    F0 A4 AD A2

When I run this code in **C#** ...

```
byte[] data = { 0xF0, 0xA4, 0xAD, 0xA2 };
string abc = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
Console.WriteLine("Test: description = {0}", abc);
```

... I redirect the output to the text file and then open it with notepad.exe choosing UTF-8 encoding. I expect to get  in the output, but do get two question marks (??).

The byte sequence is right. It works **in Perl**:

```
print "\xF0\xA4\xAD\xA2";
```

In the output, I get

**So my question is:** why do I get "??" instead of "" in **C#**?

P.S. Nothing special with this character: I got the same thing for any character (2, 3 or 4 byte long).

Comment: In the Perl case, by "in the output" do you mean you redirect the output to a text file and open it with Notepad?

Comment: You need to make sure that you write to the file using UTF8 encoding. Can you post the code for writing to the file?

Comment: Any particular reason you can't use files? Console and Unicode is somewhat painful to deal with. Oleksandr Pshenychnyy answer (+1) may help you in this case...

Comment: @JakobChristensen according to "redirect the output to the text file" there is no code to write to a file. Also good point on checking what is actual content of the file.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: You are right. I misread the question.

Comment: Strange. The anwer of Jakob was useful, but it somehow disappeared. Did you delete it?

Comment: Jim, yes, in perl I redirect to a text file and open it with Notepad.

Comment: This variant (Jakob's) seems to have helped: using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\char.txt", false, Encoding.UTF8)) {writer.WriteLine(abc);} But I am curious why someone (Jakob?) deleted this answer.

Comment: Alexey, yes, I can use files for the output. Jakob's answer has helped (please, see above). The answer of Olexander didn't work in my case (don't know why).

Comment: What about using  `WriteConsoleW` http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms687401.aspx like used here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2010/04/07/9989346.aspx ??

Comment: Amitd, thanks, sounds interesting, but I already came up with StreamWriter (please, see the example above).

Comment: @JakobChristensen, consider un-deleting your answer as it seem that what Racoon have to do. (voted to restore).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I un-deleted my answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write to a file using UTF8.  The code below shows how you may do it.  When opening the resulting file in Notepad, the character  is shown correctly:

```
string c = "";
var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(c);
var cBack = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\char.txt", false, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    writer.WriteLine(cBack);
}
```

Comment: How to do this with console?

Comment: @Paul If you are thinking about doing the same thing using console, you need to change the console code page to UTF-8 equivalent code page using "**chcp**" command (ex. `chcp 65001` for utf-8) then run the application binary and redirect the standard output to file.

Answer (score 12):

Console can't display Unicode characters by default. It displays only ASCII. To enable it display Unicode, use:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode
```

before writing to it.

But **anyway it will fail on most OS**, because Windows Command line doesn't support Unicode itself.

So, for testing purpose **it would be better to write output to file**

Comment: If it possible to set the Encoding on a console application it should be possible to set the Encoding when a command prompt is launched.  I don't disagree the output should be redirected to a file of course.

Comment: This command produces an exception: Generic Exception Handler: System.IO.IOException: The parameter is incorrect.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
   at System.Console.set_OutputEncoding(Encoding value)
   at tpam_multibyte.Program.Main(String[] args)

Comment: As I said, it will fail on Windows OS (at least up to Windows 7), because Windows console doesn't support unicode. That's why you are getting that error

Comment: Thanks. Since .Net is only intended for Windows world (if we forget about Mono), it means that I can't use this solution. But thanks, anyway.

Comment: Please read the post to the end. The solution recommended was to write to a file, not to console. By the way, you can use that solution with other encoding if you need so (but currently you don't probably)

Comment: @Oleksandr Pshenychnyy: Windows console DOES support Unicode. To make you believe install Far Manager and use it with Consolas font.